# PhantomJS: how to type text to a textbox?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

The only solution I can think of is to do it with JS, but I can't pass any variables from the phantom script to the JS I'm trying to execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/). It's a very nice PhantomJS script that allows you to easily perform this kind of web behavior.

As far as communicating with your PhantomJS script, as stands today, you have a few reliable options:

1. Pass your data in via command line args.
2. Exchange data via reading/writing of files.
3. Have your PhantomJS script call your Node.js script via GETS/POSTS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are issue in the QtWebKit bridge between C++ and JS to pass stuff up and down.
It works, but better from JS to C++ than the opposite.

We have a number of issues to address, but this is one of the highest in number one in terms of demand.

In the meanwhile, I usually "decorate" the `page` object like this:

```
var page = require("webpage").create();

page.evaluateWithParams = function(func) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1),
        str = 'function() { return (' + func.toString() + ')(',
        i, ilen, arg;

    for (i = 0, ilen = args.length; i < ilen; ++i) {
        arg = args[i];
        if (/object|string/.test(typeof arg)) {
            str += 'JSON.parse(' + JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(arg)) + '),';
        } else {
            str += arg + ',';
        }
    }
    str = str.replace(/,$/, '); }');
    return this.evaluate(str);
}
```

And then you can call a function within the scope of the page like this:

```
var a = 1, b = 2;
page.evaluateWithParams(function(arg1, args) {
    // your code that uses arg1 and arg2
}, a, b);
```

Hope this helps.

Ivan